# Sphinx returns digits instead of string in matches array

Tags: php, sphinx

I made a sphinx configuration with 10 fields.
Some of the fields are string, so I defined it in source part of configuration like this:

```
sql_attr_uint       = section_id
sql_field_string    = name
sql_field_string    = element_code
sql_field_string    = section_code
```

All indexed whell:

```
collected 18334 docs, 2.5 MB
sorted 18.9 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 18334 docs, 2460468 bytes
total 13.065 sec, 188322 bytes/sec, 1403.26 docs/sec
total 44 reads, 0.112 sec, 3255.7 kb/call avg, 2.5 msec/call avg
total 366 writes, 0.386 sec, 735.4 kb/call avg, 1.0 msec/call avg
rotating indices: successfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=3131).
```

And when I'm trying to search some query exactly from the command line, everything works fine, I see text-values of the string-fields, which I defined before. But when I'm going to sphinxapi and make the same search query it returns the same result, but instead of string-values I see digits, which changing with every query:

```
[96659] => Array
(
    [weight] => 1
    [attrs] => Array
        (
            [name] => 140436931107525
            [element_code] => 140436931107617
            [section_id] => 4016
            [section_code] => 140436931107680
        )

)
```

Please anybody, what it means? I need string-values, I don't want to make additional sql-queries to DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your sphinxapi.php file is too old. Use the one from the version of sphinx you have installed.